# How do people kill the titans in the subway tunnels so fast?

Tags: resistance-2

In Resistance 2 co-op during the subway tunnels part of the Bracknell map, there are a number of titans that teleport in at various points. Usually these guys take a lot of punishment before they go down, especially when you get the extra-strength ones that are handed out when you have a full-up party. But sometimes I get in a party where someone seems to know how to one-shot them. The things hardly get two steps out of the teleporter and they're toast.

I've personally tried the LAARK and the pulse cannon on the beasts, and as far as I can tell, either of these would need at least four shots to take down a full-strength titan. I've seen other people trying to use these weapons, and getting the same effect I do. Whatever is going on, it seems to be someone down in front, close to the titan, that whacks it. I don't think it's combined LAARK shots b/c I can usually see most of the soldier's wraith shields up.

Could this be a map glitch? Maybe there's a sweet spot from which you can get a magic shot off? It seems to be this one part of this one map where this happens. Everywhere else there are titans, they come out and stomp around for quite a while before dying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the only things that can one shot titans are LAARK and fully charged splicer ( to the face / cooling equipment ). But this works only in the campaign. In Co-op titans are more powerful. Maybe someone has found a sweet spot that works well. However, most glitches that are known are stuck units or inaccessible areas. But it is possible that it is a glitch.

OTH, it could be a combination of the following

[proximity mines](http://resistance.wikia.com/wiki/XR-87_Proximity_Mine), a whole bunch of them. As that link says they are not effective against titans but in tunnels a whole bunch of small creatures spawn and trigger then mines. Also the blast is more effective in an enclosed space.

secondly, Head shots always do more damage. So aim the LAARK or pulse cannon at the head.

thirdly, wait for the shot ( >:) ) let someone else take the first or second shot ( depending on the lobby levels ) and then shoot for the kill.

Comment: yeah, i know the wait-for-the-shot tactic, if you're close enough you can see the remaining-strength, and save the shot for when it's about dead already. but that usually takes a while before the titan is ready for it. this thing i'm talking about goes down way faster than usual. the splicer theory is intriguing though - didn't know it had comparable damage to the LAARK or pulse cannon.

Comment: splicer works in the campaign only. btw, if you can notice the class of this player it might help figure out the tactic. if anyone is able to do this, regardless of level/class, then it is a glitch

Comment: i've hung back far enough from the entrance that i can see the whole group, and i think whoever's doing it is right down in front. here's a thought - is the pulse cannon more effective at close range? maybe an op tucked in under a soldier's shield at virtually point-blank with the cannon could pull it off.

Comment: that is a good theory, i will try this next i am online :D

Comment: what i'm planning to try, soon as i get off my JC2 kick, is to tuck in under the left edge of the shield of someone who's actually under that arch (assuming you can trust he won't hang you out to dry), and administer the Pulse Cannon directly to the face of the titan. There may be something about the enclosed space amplifying the pulse.

Answer (score 1):

In the campaign a relatively quick way is to shoot it a lot with a magnum (maybe 1.5 clips) detonating the rounds and then shooting it with a LAARK until its dead. But this only really works if you have one titan unless you have more ammo to get in both guns.